# Is it v1,v2,v3,.. converging sequence of space $\mathbb{E}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

$(\mathbb{E}, \Vert{.}\Vert)$ - Banach space over scalars $\mathbb{R}$ and if $v_1, v_2, v_3,..$ it's the sequence of this space that with $\forall v\in\mathbb{E}$ a sequence $ \Vert v - v_1\Vert,\Vert v - v_2\Vert, \Vert v - v_3\Vert,...$ is real converging sequence. Is it necessary that $v_1, v_2, v_3,..$ converging sequence of space $\mathbb{E}$? Why?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I think it isn't necessary that converging sequence and it's enough to show a counterexample, but I failed with it. @MisterRiemann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your favourite two elements $u, v_1 \in \mathbb E$ and define for $n > 1$
$$ v_n = v_1+nu. $$
Then the sequence $\Vert v - v_1 \Vert, \Vert v_1 - v_2 \Vert, \Vert v_2 - v_3 \Vert$ is constantly equal to $\Vert u \Vert$ (except perhaps for the first term), and hence convergent. But
$$ \Vert v_n \Vert = \Vert v_1 + nu \Vert \geq n\Vert u \Vert - \Vert v_1 \Vert,  $$
so that $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is unbounded and hence cannot converge.

Comment: Thanks, but look, I find a mistake in that my problem and now corrected it. Will this answer stay correct? @MisterRiemann

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathbb{E}=\mathbb{R}$ and $v_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$. Then $|v_n-v_{n-1}|=1/n\rightarrow 0$. But $\{v_n\}$ is not a convergent sequence.